# Drag and drop between views

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, textview, viewgroup

I have a viewgroup with textviews that are added dynamically into the viewgroup. How would I add the ability to drag and drop a textview between other textviews.

[image: drag-and-drop-android-question]

Is there a way to detect what view you have dropped it over.

If it makes it easier the textviews could be buttons.

Comment: preferably 8 and up but im not fussed if its 11

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 2):

**On API 11 and up, you can use the built in functionality**:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

**On previous versions, you can also do it by hand**:

In theory, you have to add an onTouchListener for your views, which on action down saves the touch position relative to the view position.

Then, on receiving a touch move event, you set the position of the view to reflect that.

On receiving up event, the user has dropped the view, you check the current coordinates and compare them to the other views, if it is before another view, you move that view up and set the position of the moved view to be in line with the others again.

You can limit the dragging to only x/only y by only changing those values.